# No se me recarga el Array en la otra pantalla React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

Problema de actualización en `React Native` al agregar productos al carrito

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de `React Native` donde tengo dos pantallas principales: "Products" y "CardPayment". Estoy enfrentando un problema de actualización en la pantalla "CardPayment" cuando agrego productos al carrito desde la pantalla "Products".

Estoy utilizando `React Navigation` para navegar entre estas dos pantallas.
Tengo un contexto llamado *FilterContext* que gestiona los elementos en el carrito.
La pantalla "Products" permite a los usuarios agregar productos al carrito con el botón "Añadir".

El problema es que cuando agrego productos en la pantalla "Products" y luego navego a la pantalla "CardPayment", los productos recién agregados no se actualizan de inmediato en la pantalla "CardPayment". Sin embargo, si vuelvo a cargar la aplicación o navego a otra pantalla y regreso a "CardPayment", los productos aparecen correctamente en el carrito.

```
//Pantalla Products
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from "react";
import { FlatList, Image, StyleSheet, View, Button } from "react-native";
import MyText from "./MyText";
import {products} from '../../mocks/products.json';
import { FilterContext } from "../context/FilterContext";

export default function Products() {
  const { cartItems, setCartItems } = useContext(FilterContext);
  const addToCart =  (item) => {
    //const newItem = { ...item, cartId: Date.now() }; // Agregar un identificador único
    //setCartItems([...cartItems, item]);
    cartItems.push(item)
    console.log(cartItems)
  };
  //const filteredProducts = filterProducts(products);
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
      data={products}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View key={item.id} style={styles.container}>
          <Image source={{ uri: item.thumbnail }} style={styles.thumbnail} />
          <MyText>{item.title}</MyText>
          <MyText>Precio: {item.price}€</MyText>
          <Button title="Añadir" onPress={()=>{addToCart(item)}}/>
        </View>
      )}
    />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "lightgray",
  },
  thumbnail: {
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
});





//Pantalla CardPayment
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Image, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { FilterContext } from '../context/FilterContext';
import MyText from './MyText';

function CheckoutScreen() {
  const { cartItems, setCartItems } = useContext(FilterContext);
  const [cartUpdateFlag, setCartUpdateFlag] = useState(0);

  const removeFromCart = (itemId) => {
    const updatedCartItems = cartItems.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId);
    setCartItems(updatedCartItems);
    setCartUpdateFlag((prevFlag) => prevFlag + 1); // Incrementa el indicador de actualización
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Aquí puedes realizar acciones relacionadas con la actualización
    console.log('Se actualizó el carrito'); // Ejemplo: imprimir un mensaje en la consola
  }, [cartUpdateFlag, cartItems]); // El efecto se ejecutará cuando cartUpdateFlag cambie

  return (
    <View>
      {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
        <MyText>Todavía no tienes productos en el carrito.</MyText>
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={cartItems}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View key={item.id} style={styles.container}>
              <Image source={{ uri: item.thumbnail }} style={styles.thumbnail} />
              <MyText>{item.title}</MyText>
              <MyText>Precio: {item.price}€</MyText>
              <Button title='Eliminar' onPress={() => removeFromCart(item.id)} />
            </View>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

export default function CardPayment() {
  return <CheckoutScreen />;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'lightgray',
  },
  thumbnail: {
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
});
```

Cuando escojo productos en Products y luego me voy a la pantalla de CartPayment no se me recargan al instante

Comment: tal vez puedes agregar mas información sobre como tienes el FilterContext y como estas agregando el provider